# Search shows mutual Facebook friend, but mutual friend's profile doesn't show anywhere

Tags: facebook, friends

I was searching for a person on Facebook, e.g. John Doe. When I type in the Facebook search bar, it displays "John Doe" as the first result and indicates "1 Mutual Friend". When I click on John Doe, I can see a list of friends, but I do not have any mutual friends with John Doe.

Is this is some weird bug in Facebook? Or is there anything more to it, like we do have a mutual friend but that mutual friend has put John Doe into a restricted list or blocked him?

I've tried this after one day of finding the inconsistency, but the search bar still indicates John Doe to have one mutual friend with me, but his friends list does not show any.

Answer (score 1):

That means that you have 1 mutual friend but that person's Facebook account is currently deactivated.  That person may reactivate their account at some point and would retain their friends.  These people will show up in your own list of friends (so that you can still unfriend them if desired), but not in lists of mutual friends of in friends of others, even though they are sometimes counted in the number of mutual friends and total number of friends.